# Are there differences between .then(functionReference) and .then(function(value){return functionReference(value)})?

Tags: javascript, promise

Given a named function utilized to handle a `Promise` value

```
function handlePromise(data) {
  // do stuff with `data`
  return data
}
```

a) Passing the named function `handlePromise` as a reference to `.then()`

```
promise.then(handlePromise)
```

b) Using an anonymous or named function as parameter to `.then()` and returning the named function `handlePromise` with `Promise` value as parameter within the body of the anonymous or named function passed to `.then()`

```
promise.then(function /*[functionName]*/(data) {return handlePromise(data)})
```

Questions

1. Are there any differences between patterns a) and b)?
2. If the answer to 1. is yes, what are the differences that should be
   considered when using either pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to create a case where there is a difference when no argument is passed, but it is a stretch and generally you should pass `f` and not `function(x) { return f(x); }` or `x => f(x)` because it is cleaner.

Here is an example causing a difference, the rationale is that functions that takes parameters can cause side effects with those parameters:

```
function f() {
   if(arguments.length === 0) console.log("win");
   else console.log("Hello World");
}
const delay = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms)); // just a delay
delay(500).then(f); // logs "Hello World";
delay(500).then(() => f()) // logs "win"
```

Comment: `f.call(null, void 0)` at least appears to make the calls consistent, though what if `this` is expected to not be `null`  https://jsfiddle.net/vhnm7yzr/ ?

Comment: `.then` always executes its callbacks on the global scope like `setTimeout`.

Comment: Arrow function also returns same result for each pattern https://jsfiddle.net/vhnm7yzr/2/ . Why is element of `arguments` `load` `Event` ?

Comment: @guest271314 `arguments` aren't set in arrow functions. You're seeing the arguments of the function jsfiddle is calling when evaluating your code.

Comment: Not sure if or when to mark an Answer as "accepted"? Could there be other ways in which the patterns differ? Waited several hours for other answers to be posted, following @elclanrs 's Answer. Have a gnawing sense of unfairness each time have withdrawn an "accept" mark; as best can remember have only done so twice. The first time was due to this users' utter lack of requirement clarity. At this Question due to the fact that strict equality of the patterns is not `true` for all cases. Admittedly could have advised the post author more directly the "accept" would be withdrawn due to above fact.

Comment: Feel free to accept whichever answer helped answer your question the most. I don't mind if it's mine or not - I'm just here helping build a database of knowledge to help other programmers.

Comment: I don't see where there is a side effect here? The only difference I can spot is that `() => f()` is not the same as `x => f(x)` (which is not what the question asked about)

Comment: `() => f()` is not the same as `x => f(x)` - so it's not surprising the result is different ... try comparing (**in a .then callback**) `.then(f)` with `.then(x=>f(x))` - those two exact pieces of code, as per the question - then, if you can find any differing results, I'll be surprised

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, `function(x){return f(x)} === f`.

For more info, you may want to read about [eta-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion) in lambda calculus.

Comment: If there is no mathematically logical difference in result between the two patterns, there would be the difference of an additional anonymous or named function call at the second example? Is the additional function call at the second example not taken into consideration when computing the equation?

Comment: I think for all intents and purposes they are identical, and any performance difference is probably negligible. In practice you wouldn't use the anonymous function since it is redundant.

Comment: elclanrs @BenjaminGruenbaum has demonstrated a case where `function(x){return f(x)} === f` is not `true`. https://jsfiddle.net/vuos62rj/

Answer (score 1):

#### Logic

From a logic perspective there is not anything that would set them apart.

#### Source

From a source code and style perspective my personal taste is against inline function declarations as they are harder to read (when reading someone else's code, when reading my own its a work of art LOL)

#### Debugging

From a debugging perspective when the nesting gets deep its is harder to debug when you have a long stack trace of anonymous calls.

#### Performance

From a performance perspective it is browser dependent. With no significant difference using Firefox. Using Chrome Canary 60 and all versions before. Inline anonymous function declarations are significantly slower after the first call than defined function statements, and function expressions. This is true for both traditional and arrow functions.

Comparing the two alternatives and timing the while loop only

```
var i,j;
const f = a => a;
j = i = 10000;

while(i--) f(i);  // timed loop


while(j--) (a=>a)(j); // timed loop
```

The pre defined function is executed 870% quicker than the inline function.

But I have yet to see anyone use promises in performance critical code, the difference in time on the test machine (win10 32bit) is 0.0018µs(*) for `f(i)` and 0.0157µs for `(a=>a)(i)`

<sub>(*) µs denotes microseconds 1/1,000,000th of a second</sub>

#### Conclusion

The differences are small to insignificant, more a matter of personal taste and style than anything else. If you work in a team use the style outlined in their style guide, if you are project lead or work on your own, use what you are most comfortable with.

The edge case as shown in BenjaminGruenbaum answer I do not consider valid as he explicitly calls f() in `then(()=>f())` without an argument. That is the same as `const ff = () => f(); delay(0).then(ff)` and not a quirk of how the function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed one main difference though not so important, which actually should be avoided.
If you call handlePromise() as directly inside then() you're not allowed to add external parameters. If you call it inside function which is inside then `.then( (result) => handle(result, someOtherParam) )` then you're able to add 'someotherparam' to call. It's handy if you have bigger calls tree, though I would avoid that and pass it through whole promises chain.

**TLDR;**
first one is called with .then() results as parameters, latter one is elastic in what you want to pass further.

Comment: _"If you call handlePromise() as directly inside then() you're not allowed to add external parameters."_ Cannot `.bind()` be utilized to pass extra parameters?