# Diff b/w .then(doSomething()) and .then(() => doSomething()) in promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I've been implementing some features in javascript using promises, but am confused about one thing, difference b/w these two

```
Promise.resolve()

.then(doSomething())
```

and

```
.then(() => doSomething())
```

Comment: In first case function doSomething must return another function because .then() needs passing function.

Comment: What specifically are you confused about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`then` expects a function. In the first case, you're passing to `then` the result of calling `doSomething()`, and in the second case you're actually passing a function that calls `doSomething()`.

Those would be equivalent (assuming you don't need arguments or `this`):

```
Promise.resolve().then(doSomething)
Promise.resolve().then(() => doSomething())
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas, that's what I was looking for

Comment: *"If doSomething does use this those would be equivalent:"* That's not correct. In `() => doSomething()`, `this` inside `doSomething` will be `undefined` (or the global object).

Comment: @Lucas The patterns are not strictly equivalent

Comment: @FelixKling can you elaborate? `doSomething.bind(this)` and `() => doSomething()`, `this` inside the function will be whatever `this` is in the scope it was called.

Comment: @guest271314 can you elaborate?

Comment: Inside the *arrow* function `this` will be what it is outside. But not inside `doSomething` (called inside the arrow function). The equivalent to `doSomething.bind(this)` would be `() => doSomething.call(this)`. If a function is called "normally" (as `f()`), `this` is either `undefined` (strict mode) or the global object (unless the function is bound of course). It doesn't matter at all what `this` is in the environment the function is called. See MDN for more information about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @Lucas See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41194287/

Comment: @FelixKling Ops, missed that one. Thanks. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

`.then(doSomething())` immediately invokes `doSomething` before the `then` callback is called.

`.then(() => doSomething())` creates a new function which becomes the `then` callback.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Lucas answer, which is correct, `then` in a Promise is formulated like this (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)):

```
Promise.then(onFulfilled[, onRejected]);

Promise.then(function(value) {
   // fulfillment
  }, function(reason) {
  // rejection
});
```

So your first argument is a function for fulfillment, and your second function an argument for a rejection, both arguments being functions, to which values are passed based on that which occurred.

So, as @Lucas said,

`Promise.resolve().then(() => doSomething())` actually calls your function, where as just passing in `doSomething()` calls the function and returns a value or undefined if there is no return, which will do nothing unless that function returns a function (which would probably be an unreasonable way to go about a thenable).