# Chain promise using functions doesn't return desired callback sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

1.I'm trying to chain some promises with using functions on a global promise object. The chain sequence doesn't work as I thought. The following code output 1 3 4 2. 
2.I wonder what is the reason for this. My thought is in the variable declaration pass, p.then() function registered but not its following promises, not until the p.then() function returns, it start to push the second then function in callback queue.

To answer the question why I'm doing this, I was trying to use an builder pattern for a sequence of actions.
For example, builder().setupTestEnv().connectToDatabase().setupAuthServer().setupAuthClient(). Each function in this chain is intended to do _globalPromiseObject.then() to chain up following actions.

I know an alternative solution for this is, end the builder chain with an execute() call, which run Q.all() to run all promises in sequence. But just curious about this behavior of promise chain.

```
const Q = require('q');

const p = Q();

p
.then(
    function(){
        console.log(1);
    }
)
.then(
    function(){
        console.log(2);
    }
);

function foo(){
    p.then(
        function () {
            console.log(3);
        }
    );
}

function bar(){
    p.then(
        function () {
            console.log(4);
        }
    );
}

foo();
bar();
```

Comment: If you want *one* sequence, you should write one chain not three.

Comment: If you want the sequence 1,2,3,4, why do you make everything dependent on `p`? You have to CHAIN them, append them to one another, not to the same promise! You chain them all to the `p` promise, so the order will be the order you attached them to the chain on `p`. _Always chain a callback (using `.then(...)`) to the promise it is supposed to depend on (and wait for)._ This can be an actual chain, or you can split a chain and use variables for each step. This method also helps to create promise dependency _trees_ rather than only (linear) chains -- you are not limited to linear sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this 100% answers your question, but perhaps it is helpful to look at this in terms of meaningful statements in your example:

1. `p.then()`
2. `foo()`
3. `bar()`
4. finally, #1's `then` fires

Those three operations happen immediately after each other, *synchronously*. Let's remove the `foo` and `bar` wrappers, as if you wrote their contents in place of calling them:

1. `p.then(/* log 1 */)`
2. `p.then(/* log 3 */)` contents of foo
3. `p.then(/* log 4 */)` contents of bar
4. finally, #1's `then` fires

Comment: A `then` never fires its callback synchronously. Not sure whether I misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: @Bergi yeah. in this case, there is nothing happening _besides_ those callbacks.

Comment: Not the callback, but the calls to then itself in your program are happening synchronously, in that order.

Comment: Cool. This makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Coz I have a different understanding of the then promise chan. I thought something like Promise.then() is returned synchronously and it will then keep building its following then() chain. But it makes sense it is not doing this. coz the behavior of following then() chain is related with the return value of previous then() results. We have to resolve the first then() first to register the following then() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can `return` `foo()` and `bar()` from the respective function, then pass `foo` and `bar` to `.then()` `.then(foo).then(bar)` or `return` `foo()` and `bar()` from `.then(function(){ return foo() })`

```js
const p = Promise.resolve();

p
  .then(
    function() {
      console.log(1);
    }
  )
  .then(
    function() {
      console.log(2);
    }
  )
  .then(function() {
    return foo()
  })
  .then(function() {
    return bar()
  })

function foo() {
  return p.then(
    function() {
      console.log(3);
      return
    }
  );
}

function bar() {
  return p.then(
    function() {
      console.log(4);
      return
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: `... then(foo).then(bar)` would suffice.

Comment: @Lokua See [Are there differences between .then(functionReference) and .then(function(value){return functionReference(value)})?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41191131/)

Comment: Right on @guest271314. The answer to that question also points out that "generally you should pass `f` and not `function(x) { return f(x); }`". This goes for functions in JS in general, not just promises. `const add1 = x => x + 1; numbers.map(add1)`. `p.then(doA).then(handleAReturn).catch(handleError)` is quite elegant.

Comment: https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/ch2.html#a-quick-review