# Why can this function be referenced without a data arg provided?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I don't understand how this function that takes an arg can be called without providing the arg value. I'm guessing that since loadStrings method from the PS5 library will make an async call, there is the assumption of returned data or message, but I would still expect the arg to be provided in the function call since the function definition expects one.

Tried to find explanation for this on web but can't so far.

This is what is used and works.

```
function setup() {
  loadStrings("lines.txt", doText);
}

function doText(data) {
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    text(data[i], 5, 20*i+20);
  }
}
```

I thought that to provide an argument for the doText call, I would have to wrap it in an anonymous function to prevent immediate execution that would occur by adding the open parens after the name and then give it it's arg inside of the wrapper.

```
function setup() {
  loadStrings("lines.txt", function () {doText(data);});
}

function doText(data) {
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    text(data[i], 5, 20*i+20);
  }
}
```

So how does the data magically get passed through in the first example with no actual arg value provided?

Comment: `doText` doesn’t have parentheses after it, so it’s not a call. You’re just passing the function itself as an argument.

Comment: I understand that in the case where the function definition does not call for an argument, but doText does call for one, so that's the jist of my question/confusion. Without an arg needed, it makes sense to me. With one, I thought I wold have to be it the second way.

Comment: Take `function loadStrings(filename, someFunction) { someFunction([1, 2, 3]); }` as an example. When the function you pass in is called, it gets its argument. If you’re not calling it, you don’t need to care about what its parameters are.

Comment: In your second snippet, `function () {doText(data);}` doesn't even work - there is no `data` variable anywhere. You'd need to receive the data as a parameter `function(data) { doText(data); }` for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No magic here. As you can read in the [docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadStrings) or see in the [code of p5.js](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/io/files.js)
loadString is reading the lines of the given text file and passing the resulting array as first argument to the callback function.

Comment: Ok, so the loadStrings method is specifically set up so that any return value will always be inserted as an arg for the function referenced in it's own second arg.

Answer (score 1):

`loadStrings` appears to be a function which expects the second parameter to be a function where the argument is the result of processing the first parameter.

For example

```js
function loadStrings(a, f) {
  new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(a)
  })
  .then(f)
}

function doText(data) {
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i], 5, 20*i+20);
  }
}

loadStrings("text.txt", doText)
```

which could be considered the same as

```js
function loadStrings(a, f) {
  new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(a)
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    f(data)
  })  
}

function doText(data) {
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i], 5, 20*i+20);
  }
}

loadStrings("text.txt", doText)
```

See also [Are there differences between .then(functionReference) and .then(function(value){return functionReference(value)})?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191131/are-there-differences-between-thenfunctionreference-and-thenfunctionvalue)